# Unix script to download file in other server

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a scenario where I need to write a shell script which has to download a file in a remote directory.

Eg: I logged into Server A and from there my script needs to login to Server B and using wget command it has to download a file.

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: `ssh hostname [command]` ?

Comment: I need to download the file under specific directory say /tmp in server B. How can I specify using ssh.?

Comment: `ssh REMOTE_SERVER "cd REMOVE_DIRECTORY && wget 'URL'"`?

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour). [Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: You don't specify which file/directory to download to "using ssh" You use ssh to connect to another machine, then in that `[command]` portion that Adam has in his example, you run whatever commands you want on that remote computer. Your question is, rather, "How do I specify the directory and file to download the HTML in wget". Which, one possible answer is Cyrus's, another would be to utilize the `-O` flag in `wget`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing an SSH into Server B and then doing a wget, I would suggest that you first download the file onto Server A and then scp it to Server B at the path you want.

Comment: Server A cannot download the file. only Server B can. Now I am doing downloading in Server B manually. In order to avoid the manual stuff I am looking for options where the script in Server A will do all these.

Comment: Why cannot we write the wget script in server B itself?